# How to change the device setting configuration from application in IOS?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to change the device setting configuration from a own application in iOS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which settings? Also, probably not.

Comment: Application specific setting (managed through setting bundle).

Comment: So device settings? Or app settings? Please could you clear up your question. I'm not sure what you are asking. Maybe give a specific example of what setting you want to change.

Comment: How to modify an iOS Settings(Settings Bundle) entry from your app. Please go through the link for reference-http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/ios-how-to-create-an-ios-settings-entry-for-your-app-using-settings-bundle/

Comment: Yes, you have said that several times. I still don't know what you mean. Do you mean (for instance) the language of the device? The date/time on the device? The brightness of the screen? Or do you mean the colour theme used in the app? Or the list of favourite items in the app? etc... Specific.

Comment: suppose we have selected color theme "Dark" from the setting and we run the app. The app configures itself according to the "Dark" theme. Now from configuration screen in the app I have changed the theme from "Dark" to "Light". I want this change in theme to be reflected in the settings too. So please let me know how can I achieve this (if it is possible). Thanks.